# Assuming other variables are good, could earth plants survive the light intensity on the surface of Mercury?

Tags: terraforming

I am trying to imagine a terraformed solar system in the late 3rd millennium to early 4th millennium AD. As a result, I am curious if plants on this Mercury, which would have all the oxygen, CO2, soil nutrients, and water they need to survive the sunlight intensity on Mercury. Also, this Mercury has had its day shortened to 20 hours. MANDATORY EDIT: This Mercury has a magnetosphere that is strong enough to block a similar percentage of UVB and A that Earth's does, or what I mean is, only an Earth-like amount of radiation reaches its surface. It has a surface pressure of 96,879 millibars.

Comment: As realistic sci-fi environments go, clouds of space stations are almost always going to win over planets, even on a planetary scale. It's sort of like you've got some cave-men and they're contemplating cave-forming a distant mountain that doesn't have any caves in it, so that it has some caves to live in. Like... sure, it might be doable with enough technology and resources. But if you have the technology and resources to cave-form mountains (terraform planets), you can just build much nicer houses (space stations) for way less effort.

Comment: This question is not odd at all in this site ;)

Comment: @gs If you live on a planet, your stuff can be mined from the planet and shipped by train to you. If you live on a space station, it has to be shipped by rocket from a planet or asteroid. Rockets are a ridiculously expensive form of transportation. The cost of rockets dominates the cost of living in space.

Comment: @causative If you have left a planet (including to get to another planet), you had to have functioning space industry.  And once you have functioning space industry, stuff on planets is ridiculously expensive to get to the industry (and somewhat expensive to deliver goods to as well).  Planets become backwaters.  Delivering stuff fast by rocket is expensive, but slow deliveries aren't expensive (stuff a solar sail on it, or ion drive powered by solar panels shooting asteroid dust, or whatever): delivering terraatonnes of iron to a forge is cheaper.

Comment: @Yakk If we're talking realistic physics, shipping anything around space, even slowly with solar sails and ion drives, is incredibly challenging and expensive. Freight transport around a planet will always be far easier than freight transport in space. On Earth, the population is concentrated around oceans, lakes, and rivers, in large part because it allows cheaper naval shipping. And that's on Earth, where all shipping is much cheaper than in space. Cheap shipping dominates where people will live.

Comment: @causative It's not living on the planet that's expensive, it's the part where you ship billions of trillions of tons of matter to the planet (and then pay for its new gravitational binding energy so it doesn't vaporize your wannabe biosphere on impact). Living on Earth is cheap. Living in space is expensive. Turning Mercury briefly habitable is mind-smashingly impossible on a scale so far beyond any human endeavor that the people who could accomplish it might as well be gods. Living on a briefly-habitable Mercury is cheap again, except that you'll die young because the gravity is wrong.

Comment: @gs You don't ship billions or trillions of tons of matter to the planet. The point of having a planet is that the matter is already there. You can get it from mines and ship it cheaply around the planet. Though I do agree that terraforming Mercury or even Mars is implausible. Planet-bound civilizations would live in bubbles or underground.

Comment: @causative Except resource extraction on Earth is insanely expensive.  Cheap transportation -- to where?  To where the resources come from, or where the processed resources come from.  We have single asteroids with more metals than we can ever mine on the planet Earth, because the Earth's crust is insanely metal-light compared to asteroids (the metals on earth are trapped in the core).  And planets are expensive to ship to/from where the cheap resources are... so their shipping is expensive.  Once we have space industry, planets become backwaters.

Comment: @Yakk There are advantages to mining the asteroid belt, but it is extremely expensive to ship freight from one asteroid to another, and everything the mine needs to operate, including rocket fuel for outbound shipping, must come by rocket. Far cheaper to ship by rail from one mining site on Mars to another mining site. If an asteroid is valuable enough, crashing it into Mars and mining the crater is a strong option, because then the mine can be connected cheaply by rail to all the other resources and products on Mars.

Comment: @causative Crashing asteroids of reasonable size into planets doesn't result in a mining site - it results in a destroyed planetary surface.  We are talking larger than dinosaur killer asteroids. And moving an entire asteroid is strictly more expensive than moving the mined output, so you don't even save on the rocket fuel you seem to think is super expensive (??). (rocket fuel is energy plus mass; you'd use slag as propellant). Energy budgets to move around the solar system are as low as you want them to be, the only problem is time. Rockets are only expensive when they are fast.

Comment: Slow transport is its own cost. If your stuff takes 20 years to arrive, the opportunity cost of shipping that slow was really high! Really what we want to compare, instead of dollars, is expansion rate; would the exponential expansion rate of a civilization on Mars be higher or lower than the exponential expansion rate of a civilization mining the asteroids? Due to economies and speeds of travel, I think Mars would expand more quickly.

Comment: @Yakk It's not more expensive in terms of rocket fuel because mining requires massive inputs in terms of machinery and chemicals to separate ores, which do not have to be sent to the asteroid if you are crashing it. However, I ran the numbers and vaporization on impact would be a more significant problem than I thought. I'm not sure if most of the asteroid would vaporize, but a significant chunk would. It could be worth it anyway; whatever doesn't vaporize can later be strip mined.

Comment: @causative Mining 1 billion tonnes of ores doesn't require anywhere near 1 billion tonnes of supplies.  Delta-v (insofar as it matters) is in favour of shipping refined goods.  The main cost of transport is entering/existing gravity wells.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150110/discussion-between-causative-and-yakk).

Answer (score 8):

It seems unlikely. Ultraviolet will basically kill anything we know of at that intensity. We use it to purify water as even microscopic life can't survive it. It definitely damages plants even on Earth as anyone involved with hydroponics can attest, too much will kill them in short order as it messes with their chemistry in a myriad of ways.

Our plants have evolved for the amount they receive on Earth, too little or too much is bad for them.

One of the main things plants get from UV light is that it stresses them, and therefore causes important protective mechanisms to combat the stress. These things are great for the plant, kind of like stressing muscles to make them grow for body builders. Overdoing it will cause irreversible damage.

Comment: I don't know enough about atmosphere to complete this myself : is there no atmosphere setup that would reduce UVs without messing up every other conditions for plant's life (e.g. : Changing rain to acid, removing too much sunlight, ...)?

Comment: @Tortliena I'm just answering using the info provided and ignoring everything else.

Comment: @Tortliena: Earth's atmosphere does that, absorbing about three quarters of the ultraviolet radiation coming from the Sun. (At noon, at reasonable latitudes. In the morning and in the evening, or at high latitudes, an even larger proportion of UV is absorbed by the atmosphere.) But Mercury is *really close* to the Sun.

Comment: So what? Engineer it to build a dead  protective layer orientated towards the sun, with a green downwards layer living from stray light. Make the plant grow its own straw-hat.

Comment: A thicker layer of ozone would protect against the UV. I have no estimate on how thick the layer would have to be. The problem you'd see after that would be the solar radiation breaking down molecules into their atomic components and blowing them into space.

Answer (score 7):

**Frame Challenge: Why expose them to full direct sunlight?**

If you have the technological capacity and resources needed to Terraform Mercury you must by default also have the capacity to basically just 'green house' it. The gravity on Mercury is only about .4 of G BTW so it would have a thinner atmosphere than Earth by default and the intense radiation would strip that away very quickly.

Better to invest all your efforts in constructing a planet spanning network of giant arcologies (well as much of it as you want to anyway). You still end up a habitual planet without the hassle of dealing with the issues I raised above. Hundreds of thousands of square kilometers of the surface covered in sealed domes and towers (or any other shape you want) each stretching kilometers upwards into the sky and/or downwards into the crust. All of them with their own controlled ecosystems with Earth like air pressure, oxygen levels and weather as well as all the other comforts of home. Think rivers and seas, forests, hills, valleys and even mountains if you want. Just like the kind of thing you might see on larger space habitats only on a far grander scale. The planet would sparkle and glitter in the harsh sunlight when seen from space.

Answer (score 4):

Rainforest trees often grow high, wide leaf canopies to gather as much sunlight s they can in the jungle, simultaneously blocking most light from reaching the forest floor.
Additionally, in real life, there are many plants that grow branches or leaves that die, but remain attached to the plant. This happens with plants that live in dry areas such as deserts, so it isn't a far stretch to imagine plants on a brightly lit planet doing the same.
Your plants could combine the traits above to quickly grow a dense canopy after being planted, which then shrivels and dries up. then the plants could grow at a more reasonable pace under the shelter of the canopy, like grass sprouting up under a tree in dry areas. To accomplish the canopy growth, the plants could grow from large seeds that contain plenty of stored nutrients so they don't need the sun until after they have assembled their canopy. the disadvantage of this method would be that the canopy would be dry tinder on a baking planet. it would probably be wise for the plants to fabricate some type of flame-retardant chemical on the canopy leaves.

There's another option: the plants hide from the sun.
again, this is similar to what many real plants do, like morning glories, which open their flowers in the morning and close them later, or sunflowers, which move their flowerheads throughout the day to follow the sun during the day. your plants could have tough leaves that shield them during the day, then blossom at dusk for the plants to grow. They could even employ a hibernative state like some plants and animals, where they practically dry up in the day, perhaps storing all their water in their roots, then when the worst of the heat is gone, they could rehydrate themselves.

Third option: If your planet follows a normal spin pattern, there is probably somewhere like our poles that gets less light than most of the planet for at least part of the year, meaning that plants without to many special adaptations could survive there, especially if they have shelter from rocks, mountains, or other natural formations.

Fourth  option: Water plants. Plants that live in swamp-like or even fully submerged environments.
Apologies for the length of this answer, your question really got me thinking. Thank you!

Comment: If an answer is good, its length is no objection. Also the question can be solved or evaded by several approaches, mentioning several usually helps.

Answer (score 2):

> "... Also, this Mercury has had its day shortened to 20 hours..."

If your future-science civilization has the technological power to alter the very spin of an entire planet... then surely they have the ability to build a [sunshield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_sunshade) or two.

Comment: Foeget about sunshields. All you need is a block of concrete suspended a few meters above a plant.